# Vscode interactive python, running a command without making a cell?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, interactive

Currently, running [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmNH2.png) command would add it as a cell but is it possible to just run the command without having it be added? this could be something i am only doing once for testing purposes

shift-enter or clicking execute code results in [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtLzJ.png)

Comment: There's a long running [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4573) for this. It's possible in regular Jupyter Labs, but not supported in VS Code at the moment.

Comment: is that first screenshot from VS Code? Or something else?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Where would you expect the result to be shown? Just delete the cell after you looked at the result